# What is capital X in Processing?

Tags: processing

What is capital `X` in Processing? It's a system variable, but I don't see any documentation anywhere regarding its purpose.

It's not the origin, because I can move the origin with translate and it remains the same value, zero.

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  translate(100,100);
  println(X); // always zero in this code
}
```

I ask this question because X repeatedly shows up in student code without being declared or initialized and it compiles. It seems like a pointless variable. Assigning it a value has no side effect I can detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to modify this variable X, and I got the following error message:

```
    The final field PConstants.X cannot be assigned
```

Looking into the processing github, I found [this page](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PConstants.html), which states that X is a static variable shared throughout the Processing Core. It is final, which means that it cannot be modified. Essentially, X=0 because it is. It will throw the above error if you try to reassign it as well.

Comment: In Java, can I 'mask' a variable by re-declaring it? It seems to be possible to declare the X elsewhere in code such as `int X = 5`.

Comment: I gave it a go and it worked fine. It might be an issue if you ever want to use that originally defined value, but if you don't want to, then I don't think that anything is stopping you.

Comment: I can't find any functions that take the `X`, `Y`, or `Z` variables as an argument. Do you know what they're actually used for?

Comment: I've looked around the processing github and tried to find a use for it, but I couldn't. I'm not sure that they're used for anything, so if you want to redefine them, you shouldn't encounter any issues, at least none that I could find.